# To Insert Checkbox Values into Database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Currently I am doing a project in php for uploading CSV file and to insert data into database. Before Inserting I need to display the data in checkboxes and to insert the values that are checked.

With this code after uploading it displays data with checkbox but on clicking the checkbox the values are not inserting into database.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))
{
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
}

$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
echo("<table border='1'>");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
    echo("<tr>\r\n");
    foreach ($data as $index=>$val)
    {
        echo("\t<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk1[]' value='$val'>$val</td>\r\n");
    }
    echo("</tr>\r\n");
    }
    echo("</table>");
echo("<td><input type='submit' name='insert' id='insert' value='Submit' /></td>");
fclose($handle);
}
```

For Inserting the selected data into database I am using this code.

```
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
for($i=0;$i < sizeof($checkbox1);$i++)
{
$query = "INSERT INTO uploadmail (name,email) VALUES ('$name','".$checkbox1[$i]."')";
echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query);
}
}
```

After clicking checkboxes when I click Submit button it is not doing any action.So Please give me any suggestions.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0):

> Your table closed before the form submit. And please maintain the table structure if you are using form in a table. Close all input fields in table's td followed by "tr".
>   And here its understood that you assigned $checkbox1 = $_POST['chk1'];